# How to get a username in Active Directory from a display name in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I want to be able to obtain the userid of a user in Active Directory using the display name of that user. The display name is obtained from a database, and has been stored during that user's session using the following code to obtain the display name:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

    private string GetDisplayName()
    {
        // set up domain context
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        // find currently logged in user
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;

        return user.DisplayName;
    }
```

This time around, I would like to have a method named `GetUserIdFromDisplayName()` that returns the Active Directory login name. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't verified it, so I'm not 100% sure, but I think you want the `SamAccountName` property.

Comment: Do you think, this is possible? I doubt that user display names are unique. Would possibly lead to multipe results.

Comment: True. I now consider using GUIDs instead using the answer below.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I believe you can do it much more easily than with David's answer by using the built-in functionality of the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace.

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

private string GetUserIdFromDisplayName(string displayName)
{
    // set up domain context
    using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        // find user by display name
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, displayName);

        // 
        if (user != null)
        {
             return user.SamAccountName;
             // or maybe you need user.UserPrincipalName;
        }
        else
        {
             return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see any need to go to the underlying `DirectoryEntry` object, really - unless none of the properties of the `UserPrincipal` really are what you're looking for.

PS: if the search by display name shouldn't work (I don't have an AD at hand to test it right now) - you can always also use the `PrincipalSearcher` to find your user:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

private string GetUserIdFromDisplayName(string displayName)
{
    // set up domain context
    using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
        // and with the display name passed in
        UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
        qbeUser.DisplayName = displayName;

        // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
        PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

        // find match - if exists
        UserPrincipal user = srch.FindOne() as UserPrincipal;

        if (user != null)
        {
             return user.SamAccountName;
             // or maybe you need user.UserPrincipalName;
        }
        else
        {
             return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, easier and quicker, and finds DOMAIN\USERID entries as well

Comment: I was able to find users by their DOMAIN\USERNAME with `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityTypes.SamAccountName, username)`, so I assume you want to return `user.SamAccountName` like the code states.

Comment: FindByIdentit() is find by user principle. User principle is not essentially same as Display Name. If you create a new user with display name "ABC". Later you can change it to "A B C". The user principle will not be updated and above script will not find this user.

Answer (score 8):

`UserPrincipal` has a method `GetUnderlyingObject()` which will return the `DirectoryEntry`.

**Get DirectoryEntry from Principal:**

```
private DirectoryEntry GetDirectoryEntryFromUserPrincipal(Principal user)
{
    return (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();
}
```

**Get DirectoryEntry from domain and account name:**

```
private DirectoryEntry GetDirectoryEntryFromDomainAndUsername(string domainName, string userName)
{
    // Get the sid from the NT account name
    var sid = (SecurityIdentifier) new NTAccount(domainName, accountName)
                  .Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));

    // Get the directory entry for the LDAP service account
    var serviceEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://{address}", "serviceUsername", "servicePassword");

    var mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(serviceEntry)
        {
            Filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectSid={0}))", sid.Value)
        };

    return mySearcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry();
}
```

Once you have the `DirectoryEntry` use the `Guid` property to get the entry's [Object-Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
private Guid GetObjectGuidFromDirectoryEntry(DirectoryEntry entry)
{
    // return the Guid this is the Object-Guid (ignore NativeGuid)
    return entry.Guid;
}
```

**For tracking a user account in the application against a directory account: always use the Object-Guid as "This value is set when the object is created and cannot be changed."**
NT and SAM account names can change if the user changes domains or, more commonly, changes their name (marriage, legal name-change, etc.) and should not be used to track a user.

**To get the NT account name (domain\username):**

```
private string GetNTAccountNameFromDirectoryEntry(DirectoryEntry entry)
{
    PropertyValueCollection propertyValueCollection = entry.Properties["objectsid"];

    SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[]) propertyValueCollection[0], 0);

    NTAccount ntAccount = (NTAccount)sid.Translate(typeof (NTAccount));

    return account.ToString();
}
```

**To get the SAM-Account-Name (username@domain):**

```
private string GetSAMAccountFromDirectoryEntry(DirectoryEntry entry)
{
    return entry.Properties["Name"].Value;
}
```

And here's the [exhaustive list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of all the Active Directory attributes. Use the "Ldap-Display-Name" when getting the value from `Properties`
e.g. `Properties["Ldap-Display-Name"]`

[Display-Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675514%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (FirstName MI LastName) might come in handy.

Comment: Thanks! Then I suppose you have to obtain `UserPrincipal` objects from an AD group by doing something like this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/ecb16a63-6619-4c68-a77c-8bb2682fc1be

Comment: That would work.  I saw you were using `UserPrincipal.Current` in your question.  This works if the web app is hosted in the domain, using "Windows Security", or is a native app running in a user session.  

If you can only query AD, then get the directory entry directly by filtering by SAM-Account-Name.

Comment: Added GetDirectoryEntryFromDomainAndUsername.  This might need a bit of tweaking as I'm not in an environment where I can test all this against an AD server.